# Is it possible to switch to a database on a linked server using a 'USE' statement in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've tried the obvious:

```
USE linkedServerName.databaseName
```

Which gives me the error:

```
`Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'linkedServerName'.
```

If something like this were possible, it'd save me a bunch of clicking around in management studio!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked server definitions are designed for use as part of the four-part naming convention:

```
[LinkedServerDefinition.][DatabaseName.][SchemaName.]DatabaseObject
```

for example, OtherServer.Database.dbo.MyTable

They might have other uses, but with the USE statement is not one of them.

Would

```
SELECT * from LinkedServerDefinition.master.sys.databases
```

help in identifying what databases are "over ther"?